# Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" because "session" is null

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am getting `Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" because "session" is null`

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Servlet.setContentType(request, response);
    
    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session.getAttribute("userCategory") != null && session.getAttribute("userId") != null
                && session.getAttribute("userName") != null) {

            // remove session
            session.removeAttribute("userCategory");
            session.removeAttribute("userId");
            session.removeAttribute("userName");
            session.invalidate();

            // back button or F5 not show secure pages back to the user
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

            // logout and forward a page
            response.sendRedirect("/");
            return;

            /*
             * return; <-- is important Otherwise the code will continue to run and hit some
             * session.getAttribute() method further down in the block causing exactly this
             * exception.
             */
            
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        EmailErrorsToAdmin.setMsg(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e);
    }
}
```

I am extremely sorry I just found this piece of code is throwing error Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" because "session" is null

Previously I was having doubt that when I am creating session then its throwing Cannot invoke "javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" because "session" is null but just found its giving error in Logout class

Please advise where I am making mistake?

Best Regards

Comment: There is nowhere in the code you have posted where you invoke `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)`. If you post the relevant code in the question it will increase our possibilities to help you.

Comment: In this method I am only setting setAttribute not getting any Attribute

Comment: And your exception says session is null when you are invoking `getAttribute(String)`. So it is much better that you show us the code where you get the error. It is not in the code you have in the question.

Comment: You are absolutely right this is error due to getAttribute(String). I have posted my relevant code in my question. please check it

Comment: `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);` so this line then returns null. According to the javadoc this can happen when you set the argument create to `false`: "If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null."

See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)

Comment: Most likely you want to create a session if none exist in that case you need to set the create parameter to true instead of false.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of your line:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-):

> If `create` is `false` and the request has no valid `HttpSession`,
> this method returns null.

This indicates the request has no session, so `request.getSession(false)` is returning null and setting your variable `session` to null.

You should check if your variable `session` is null before calling methods on it. It looks like your code is trying to clear the session on logout, but if there is no session there is nothing to clear.

Comment: May I do like this:`HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   if(session == null || session.equals(null)) {
    response.sendRedirect("adminLogin");
   }
   else {`

Comment: You can do something like that but reduce `session == null || session.equals(null)` to `session == null`. `session.equals(null)` can never be true as it will cause a NullPointerException if session is null and that you have already covered with `session == null`.